# How to integrate SSL certificate in POST request in ionic 2 angular 2

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, ssl-certificate, ionic3

How to integrate SSL certificate in POST request in ionic 2 angular 2 .

I have tried with http request with below code, and it is working as expected.

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
{ var headers = new Headers();
 headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic 7d04ba4e-6d56-446c-8d11-65fd2ddfc701');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
console.log('URL'+apiUrl);

this.http.post(apiUrl,options)
.timeout(10000)
.subscribe(res =>{
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(res.json());
console.log('success'+myJSON);
resolve(res.json());
}, (err) =>{
reject(


----------


err);
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use "https://" url and use the classical http.get('https....') from Http ;) The service handles both request

Add in node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/serve-webpack.js in the webpackDevServerConfiguration :

```
    cert: fs.readFileSync(process.cwd()+ '/ssl/server.crt', 'utf8'),
    key: fs.readFileSync(process.cwd()+ '/ssl/server.key', 'utf8'),
    https: true
```

Then you can ng serve --ssl 1 --ssl-key "../server.key" --ssl-cert "../server.crt"

Comment: actually we have client certificate that need to add before calling https api

Comment: That's a server side action, you need to register your ssl key and then start with that parameters :  ng serve --ssl 1 --ssl-key "../server.key" --ssl-cert "../server.crt"

Post edited

Comment: Do you have tutorial we can follow ?